# Keyboard doesn't hide in iOS even on resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uikeyboard

I have a login page with username,password textfield and a submit button.
If the focus is on password textfield and the user presses the submit button without pressing the return key on keyboard.
The keyboard is dismissed as i uses resignFirstResponder to dismiss the keyboard but when i hit the server and the alert comes of invalid credentials,then within nano seconds when alert is shown,keyboard also appears.
Used the below line of code to dismiss keyboard on Login Button click.

```
[self.passwdTxtFld setDelegate:self];
[self.usernameTxtFld setDelegate:self];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Below is the code from where i get the response from server and also displays the alert.

```
- (void)checkLogin
{



    NSLog(@"???%@",self.usernameTxtFld.text);
    NSDictionary *checkLogin=[pwInteract initializeWithOrgId:@"JVVC" AppId:@"JVVC" LoginId:self.usernameTxtFld.text Password:self.passwdTxtFld.text];

    NSLog(@"checklogin is %@",checkLogin);
    if(checkLogin)
    {
        if(![[checkLogin objectForKey:@"NOTIFICATION"]isEqualToString:@"Y"] && ![[checkLogin objectForKey:@"NOTIFICATION"]isEqualToString:@"NV"]){
            [loggingInAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:loggingInAlert.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
            [loggingInAlert removeFromSuperview];

        NSLog(@"?? response is %@",checkLogin);
        NSString *result = [checkLogin objectForKey:@"IS_AUTH"];
        NSString *error = [checkLogin objectForKey:@"ERROR"];

        if ([result isEqualToString:@"Y"] )
        {
            if([self.usernameTxtFld.text isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"]]){
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"olduser" forKey:@"usertype"];

            }
            else{
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"newuser" forKey:@"usertype"];

            }


            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"" forKey:@"fetch"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"" forKey:@"state"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"success" forKey:@"state"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.usernameTxtFld.text forKey:@"username"];




            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"success" sender:nil];

        }
        else if (![error isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *networkAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            networkAlertView.tag = 1;
            [networkAlertView show];
            [self.view endEditing:YES];

            if([self.passwdTxtFld isFirstResponder]){
                NSLog(@"pass");
            }

            if([self.usernameTxtFld isFirstResponder]){
                NSLog(@"ddd");
            }
        }
        else if ([result isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSString *error = [checkLogin objectForKey:@"ERROR"];
            UIAlertView *networkAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            networkAlertView.tag = 3;
            [networkAlertView show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *networkAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Oops! Either Username or Password is incorrect. Please type correct Username and Password to proceed." delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            networkAlertView.tag = 3;
            [networkAlertView show];

        }
    }

        else if([[checkLogin objectForKey:@"NOTIFICATION"]isEqualToString:@"NV"]){
            [customAlert hideActivityIndicator];


        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *networkAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Server Error" message:@"No Response From Server." delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        networkAlertView.tag = 3;
        [networkAlertView show];
    }

}
```

On click event of login button have resigned both the username and password textfield,also the UITextFieldDelegate are connected.
[image: you can see in the image that both UIAlertView and Keyboard are opened.]

Comment: Instead of the picture show us your code ;) What about view.endEditing(true)

Comment: It seems om error your textField are geeting focus which is triggering the keyboard to appear. Try [self.view endediting:yes] when your alert appears or when you click login button.

Comment: [self.passwdTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
    [self.usernameTxtFld resignFirstResponder];

Comment: @ArunGupta tried that also

Comment: Show the line of code that you call to dismiss the keyboard. Without code we can't help you.

Comment: @Mike i have added the line of code on button click.

Comment: Show the code around where you display that alert. That shouldn't cause the keyboard to show, unless you're setting the first responder again.

Comment: @Mike added the code where i get the repine from server and shows the alert.

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake:-**

*According to your code you are just resigning your keyboard in one "else if" condition:-*

```
else if (![error isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            UIAlertView *networkAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            networkAlertView.tag = 1;
            [networkAlertView show];
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

What about the others else if condition, Things will be resolved if you resign keyboard  `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in the very first statement of  `(void)checkLogin` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try [self.view endEditing:YES] when you tap login button or just before you show alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

or try

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   
    return YES;
}

// It is important for you to hide the keyboard
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Also check `UITextFieldDelegate` delegate method